# Help needed in a quiz question related to continuity of f'(x)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This question was asked in my real analysis quiz and I am unable to prove it true/ false.

> State True/False -> Let f : $\mathbb{R}$-> $ \mathbb{ R} $ be a differentiable function. Then f'(x) is continuous.

> I thought that f'(x) can be discontinuous as differentiability of f implies continuity of f not anything about f'(x) but I am unable to find an example. I tried sin(1/x) ,  cos(1/x) but it couldn't be such an example.

Comment: Is this question on an active quiz?

Comment: This must have been covered in class, otherwise it's too hard.

Comment: Try playing with $x^2 \sin(1/x)$ instead. Note that it is squeezed between two functions $-x^2$ and $x^2$, which are differentiable at $0$.

Comment: OK here is the general rule of thumb in real-analysis. If you have not proved $X$ or seen $X$ as a standard theorem then most likely $X$ is false. Don't rely on typical examples.

Comment: @Michael Burr why are you thinking that?

Comment: @Parmanand Singh I was asked to provide a counterexample if it's false so can you provide any?

Comment: @user Didn't you want a differentiable function with non-continuous derivative? What's wrong with user803264's example?

Comment: @user Your question stated that this was from a quiz.  But you didn't state whether this was from a quiz that you had taken (and turned in) or whether it was from a quiz that you were currently taking.  Getting help on active assignments quizzes/exams/competitions is typically frowned upon here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false, you can use this example:
$$\ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin(\frac {1}{x}) & \mbox{ if } x \ne 0 \\ 0 & \mbox{ if } x = 0 \end{cases}$$
so as you can see  $f'(0)=0$ but  $${\displaystyle \lim _{x\to 0}f'(x)=\lim _{x\to 0}\left[2x\sin(\frac {1}{x})-\cos(\frac {1}{x})\right]\neq 0  \ \ (the \ limit \ doesn't \ exist)}$$ so $f'$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: The notation $\lim \ne 0$ seems to indcate the limit exists but is not equal to $0.$ But that's not what is going on.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I will change it.